# Converting hexadecimal string to integer

Tags: elixir

I have a packet of hexadecimal values that I'm trying to deal with.  They come in as a string.  For example, one piece of the packet is `C0`, which is `192`.  However, I'm not quite sure how to translate the string value into the integer value.

If I use this:

```rb
Base.decode16!("C0")
# <<192>>
```

... I get a binary.

The only way I can think to extract this integer value is like so:

```rb
<<x>> = Base.decode16!("C0")
x
# 192
```

This works, and it seems sort of idiomatic, but I'm new to Elixir and bit unsure if this is the best solution.  How would you go about translating a string hex value into an integer in Elixir?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Integer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html)

```
Integer.parse("C0", 16) # returns {192, ""}
```

To convert it back you can use

```
# to charlist
Integer.to_charlist(192, 16) # returns 'C0'

# to string
Integer.to_string(192, 16) # returns "C0"
```

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: "** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Integer.parse/2"

Comment: Maybe you have older elixir version? I tested it with elixir 1.1.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Yep, I'm running 1.0.4.  I'll go ahead and upgrade.

Comment: @ElliotLarson This is the nice way of doing this, btw :) Be sure to check out `Integer.to_string/2` (instead of `to_char_list`) as well, and also `String.to_integer/2`.

Comment: @whatyouhide I like your idea much better. `Integer.to_string/2` and `String.to_integer/2` sounds very natural for conversion.

Answer (score 9):

You can convert a binary to the integer it represents through [`:binary.decode_unsigned/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#decode_unsigned-1):

```
iex> 192 |> :binary.encode_unsigned |> Base.encode16
"C0"
iex> "C0" |> Base.decode16! |> :binary.decode_unsigned
192
```

Comment: Do you know how you can achieve the same thing with pattern matching?